# How to pass variable value through classes in different files?

Tags: python, class, variables, scope, global

I have this problem.
I need to pass an "a" variable processed in an execute () method in a class A
To an execute () method located in a class B in a different file.

below my code:

fileA.py

```
a = 0

class A:
    
    def execute(self):
        
        global a
        
        a = 10
```

fileB.py

```
from fileA import A

    class B:
        
        def execute(self):
            
            b = a
            
            print (b)
```

main.py

```
from fileA import A
from fileB import B

    if __name__== "__main__":
        
        first = A()
        
        first.execute()
        
        second = B()
        
        second.execute()
```

If i try this i get an error:

AttributeError: type object 'A' has no attribute 'a'

How can I make that the value of the variable "a" (elaborated in method of class A) is also seen inside a method of class B ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I recommend doing some reading on "dependency injection" (or [IoC](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/ioc/introduction)). It will not only solve your problem but will also help improving your programming skills!

Comment: Generally, the way you communicate between methods is by passing in data as an argument and returning data.

Answer (score 1):

I think that there is a misunderstanding about `global` and `import`.

`import` is reponsible for 2 different things:

- the module is loaded into the `sys.modules` list and executed
- the identifiers are made available in current scope

`global` only says that the referenced variables should be searched only in module scope and skip any local scope.

Now what happens.

fileA declares a class (`A`) and a variable (`a`). And class `A` only contains an `execute` method and no other attribute. `A.execute` just happens to set the value of the module level `a` variable.

fileB imports the class `A` from fileA, but not the module level variable `a`. But it uses a variable `a` in the `B.execute` method, while it has never been declared neither in module scope nor in local one, hence the error.

How to fix:

At the simplest level, you could import into fileB module the variable `a` (that you use)   instead of the class `A` that you do not:

fileB.py

```
from fileA import a

class B:
    
    def execute(self):
        
        b = a
        
        print (b)
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd better do something like this:

fileA.py

```py
class A():
    def __init__(self, a=0):
        self.a = a

    def execute(self):
        self.a = 10
```

fileB.py

```py
class B():
    def __init__(self, class_a, b=0):
        self.class_a = class_a
        self.b = b

    def execute(self):
        self.b = self.class_a.a
        print(self.b)
```

main.py

```py
from fileA import A
from fileB import B

if __name__== "__main__":

    first = A()
        
    first.execute()
        
    second = B(first)
        
    second.execute()
```

you can skip the init part for `self.a` and `self.b` but it's much better to keep it

Answer (score 0):

Use composition.

In module_a:

```
class A:
    a = 0

    def set_a(self):
        self.a = 10
```

In module_b:

```
from module_a import A

class B:
    a = A()

    def execute(self):
        print(a.a)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    b = B()
    b.a.set_a()
    b.execute()
```